# Verify if $\sup(A) = +\infty$, where $A=\{\frac{2}{x-1} : x > 1\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Verify if $\sup(A)=+\infty$, where $$A=\{\frac{2}{x-1} : x > 1\},$$ using the definition and no limit.

My steps:

$$\frac{2}{x-1}=1$$
$$\frac{2}{x-1}-1=0$$
$$\frac{2-x+1}{x-1}=0$$
$$\frac{3-x}{x-1}=0$$
D: $x\neq1$ so $3-x=0$ and $x=3$

Are my steps right of there is a different way to solve this type of exercise?

Comment: Please explain why downvote

Comment: Why would you be interested in solving $\frac2{x-1}=1$ to determine $\sup A$? Please explain.

Comment: You're being downvoted because many people on this website are spiteful of those who ask "basic" questions. Your approach may not be the most effective, but you did put effort into the question, which is what we want.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Please do not present as objective truth, a personal conception of yours (expressed in a spiteful way).

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 The point is not that the question is "basic". It seems like the OP's approach does not show any effort in tackling the exercise; you won't try to solve $2/(x-1)=1$ if you really spent time reading the definition of $\sup$.

Comment: @Yuxiao Xie we don't know how much time he spent on doing the problem. Perhaps this was the first time that he does rigorous mathematics and he was not taught (quite well) on how to prove things from definition. I think partial answers like tommy xu3 gave is more useful than downvotes in this case.

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi Why did you ask for explanations of votes on your question? You received some but your reaction to these explanations is, so far, null...

Comment: @LiChunMin I agree with you. I just explained the possible reasons for people's downvotes. By the way I didn't downvote. :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your steps meant, but give my opinions.

To show $\sup \{\frac{2}{x-1}:x>1\}=\infty,$ what you need to verify is $\forall r>0,~\exists x>1$ such that $\frac{2}{x-1}>r.$

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to show that given a real number $r \in \mathbb R$ there is some $a\in A$ such that $a \ge r$

Since every $a\in A$ is of the form  $\frac{2}{x-1}$ for  $x > 1$ you are looking for an $x>1$ such that $\frac{2}{x-1} \ge r$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_n=1+1/n$. Then $ \frac{2}{x_n-1}=2n$.

Consequence: $2n \in A$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Your turn !